# How do i create a breadcrumb based on Main Navigation Menu in programatically?

Tags: 8, breadcrumbs

I want to display the breadcrumb according to the main navigation menu.

If i've a menu structure like 
a->b
  ->c
  ->d
e->f
  ->g
Now if i go to menu **a->c**, now the breadcrumb shows **Home > c** but i want it as like **a >b**
How to do it programatically ?

Comment: whats the name of theme you using

Comment: custom theme (subtheme of bootstrap)

Comment: Go to appearence subtheme settings. In components under breadcrumb there are settings did you notice that

Comment: but that didn't solve my issue

Answer (score 0):

[Menu breadcrumb](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_breadcrumb) module create breadcrumb based on a menu. Maybe this could help.